# MailGun store action executing notification POST with 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' instead of JSON body

Tags: python, json

I've created the following store action

`store(notify="http://my_app:1234/key/callback").`

I'm expecting to recieve a POST with the JSON body, but instead I'm getting POST with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

The MailGun documentation says (https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#routes):

> When storing an email through a store() action in a Route, you can chose to be notified when the message is stored by including a URL with the notify parameter when setting up the store action or you can retrieve the message later by searching for the message through the Events API and retrieving it through the Messages API.
>
> If you set a URL to be posted when the message is received (store(notify="http://test.com/callback")), or retrieve the message later through a GET request to the Messages API, the following parameters are posted/returned in JSON.

And yet, I'm getting the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of JSON.

What should I do, to get a JSON instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?